# The text becomes small, the navbar has no more styles when i add a new link bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

hello I have a problem in my code when I add the following bootstrap link:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">` , the shape of the page becomes strange and the text becomes small I do not understand why can you help me please !!

[page before adding bootstrap link indicate at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Njq6.png)
[page before adding bootstrap link indicate at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma0iO.png)

[page after adding bootstrap link indicate at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22TuR.jpg)
[page after adding bootstrap link indicate at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twgQ2.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.6.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">


    
</head>
<body>

    <header id="accueil">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#accueil">Accueil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#apropos">A propos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bootstrap-contact-form/bootstrap-contact-from.php" target="_blanck">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>


        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="banner" style="background-image: url(img/slide1.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2 class="animated bounceInRight" style="animation-delay: 1s">Nous sommes <span> Créatifs</span></h2>
                        <h3 class="animated bounceInLeft" style="animation-delay: 2s">Création des sites internet</h3>
                        <p class="animated bounceInRight" style="animation-delay: 3s"><a href="#">Contactez-nous</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="banner" style="background-image: url(img/slide3.jpg); background-size: cover;"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2 class="animated slideInDown" style="animation-delay: 1s">Nous sommes <span>Créatifs</span></h2>
                        <h3 class="animated fadeInUp" style="animation-delay: 2s">Création des sites internet</h3>
                        <p class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay: 3s"><a href="bootstrap-contact-form/bootstrap-contact-from.php" target="_blanck">Contactez-nous</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="banner" style="background-image: url(img/slide1.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2 class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay: 1s">Nous sommes <span>Diligent</span></h2>
                        <h3 class="animated fadeInLeft" style="animation-delay: 2s">Création des sites internet</h3>
                        <p class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay: 3s"><a href="#">Contactez-nous</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

<section id="apropos" style="height:100vh;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">A Propos De <span style="color: black;">Nous</span></h2>
    <p class="p">je suis freelance et créateur de site internet,
    j’offre des solutions spécialisées aux entreprises à travers la refonte ou la création de leur site, de leur blog professionnel
    ou la réalisation de leur solution e-commerce. La création de votre site est accompagnée d’une prestation en optimisation pour
    le référencement et à la gestion de site .</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row table-row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
            <div class="section-content">
            </div>
          </div>

          <img src="img/propos.jpg" class="big" >

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="section-content">
              <div class="about-content center animated" data-animate="fadeInLeft">
                <div class="about-icon"><i class="fas fa-cube"></i></div>
                <div class="about-detail">
                  <h3>Concept et cahier des charges</h3>
                  <p>Conception et recherche de duheuhduheufonctionnalités en adéquation avec vos objectifs.</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="about-content left animated" data-animate="fadeInLeft">
                <div class="about-icon"><i class="fa fa-code blue-lignt-color"></i></div>
                <div class="about-detail">
                  <h3>Développement et webdesign</h3>
                  <p>Programmation et développement conformes aux standards. Créations graphiques originales ou adaptation de template en fonction du budget.</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="about-content rightanimated" data-animate="fadeInLeft">
                <div class="about-icon"><i class="fa fa-desktop blue-lignt-color"></i></div>
                <div class="about-detail">
                  <h3>Webmastering, maintenance et référencemente</h3>
                  <p>Et après la mise en ligne ? Besoin d'un accompagnement, d'une aide à la rédaction ou à la maintenance technique, d'aller plus loin dans le référencement ?</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d159a133a6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? These look like entirely different websites

Comment: Your page is setup to use Bootstrap 3.3.7, which has its own set of classes that are different from Bootstrap version 4 (which is the version of Bootstrap you’re trying to add). If you want to migrate to version 4 (or 5), you will need to change parts of your code.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I’m talking about. Can you help me  my to change part of my code please ?

Comment: If you want to reply to a comment, you need to put the commenter’s name (@RichDeBourke). Only the original poster gets notified of activity on the post. I don’t think there’s any documentation on how to go from Bootstrap 3 to 5, but there are pages to help migrate from [3 to 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) and from [4 to 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/). Depending on how much code you have written, you might be better off starting over again using Bootstrap 5 rather than trying to migrate.